# codeigniter method structure, can someone explain me?

Tags: codeigniter

Im really curious how does codeigniter achieve something like this:

$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)

it looks like method chaining, but it's not. How would the structure of this look in plain OOP?

I suppose its not as simple as..?

```
public function upload()
{
    // stuff
    return $this;
}

public function do_upload()
{
    // stuff
    return $foo;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: just read this you will have some idea http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html[link]

Answer (score 0):

When you load the library in your controller it's actually doing something like this behind the scene.

```
include 'system/libraries/Upload.php';
$this->upload = new CI_Upload();
```

Now you have "$this->upload" ready to use,

Next when you call "$this->upload->do_upload()" you're actually calling a method within the library.

On the other hand Method chaining, is just a matter of making methods returns an instance of the same object, You can review this in libraries code in CodeIgniter 3 on GitHub.
Where most library uses method chaining now.